# How to convert png images files to gif format?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some `.png` images, and I want to create animated `.gif` of them, but I need first to convert them to `.gif` format.

This is what I tried:

But I am unsure how to convert in the foreach loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using unfreez_wrapper;

namespace Animated_Gif
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        UnFreezWrapper unfreez;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\New folder (3)");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {

            }
            unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();
            unfreez.MakeGIF(files.ToList(), @"d:\anim.gif", 1000, true);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I need first to convert them to .gif format

If you do so, you limit yourself to have only up to 256 colors in all frames. Unless this is what you really want I recommend to use the actual input frames instead and allow the encoder to optimize the delta frames, which may allow using more colors if possible.

As you tagged `winforms` in your question a simple solution can be to use [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_SaveAsAnimatedGif_2.htm) method from [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#advanced-gif-encoder-with-high-color-support) library (disclaimer: written by me). If you omit the `quantizer` parameter it allows creating an animation that has more than 256 color per frames. And even if you want to restrict the colors of all frames you don't need to convert each frames manually first just use some quantizer, eg. from [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_PredefinedColorsQuantizer.htm) class.

**Examples:**

| Description | Image |
| --- | --- |
| Input frames | [image] |
| Result of [`SaveAsAnimatedGif`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_SaveAsAnimatedGif_2.htm) with no quantizer specified (uses [`Wu`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_OptimizedPaletteQuantizer_Wu.htm) by default) | [image] |
| Using [`Grayscale`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_PredefinedColorsQuantizer_Grayscale.htm) quantizer with silver background | [image] |